# java set exponent length

Tags: java, rsa

I'm using `KeyPairGenerator` to generate RSA keypair. Now my other application needs that the exponent has to be 4 bytes long. Is there a way to set it so `KeyPairGenerator` would use 4 bytes exponent instead os 3 bytes?

Comment: padding with zeros is not an option, I assume?

Comment: Well, i found a place sayng that Pad at the leading octets. but i have no idea how to do that..

Comment: Why exactly does your other application need the exponent stored as 4 bytes? You really need to know what format it's expecting the output to be in. Typically RSA keys are represented as `BigInteger` values in Java. Is your other application Java or something else?

Comment: Other application is javacard application

Comment: You must be wrong because almost every RSA public exponent in use is 65537, a 3 byte value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.security.KeyPairGenerator` can be initialized with an instance of `java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec`, in which you can set the public exponent to use. Just choose a "4 bytes exponent" (whatever this means). RSA requires the public exponent to be an odd positive integer (not 1); prime values are preferred (but not mandatory).